# Where do you find the interface for phpmyadmin when installed using homebrew

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I installed `phpmyadmin` using `homebrew`

```
brew install phpmyadmin
```

The output came back as follows:

```
Note that this formula will NOT install mysql. It is not
required since you might want to get connected to a remote
database server.

Webserver configuration example (add this at the end of
your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for instance) :
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
  <Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
Then, open http://localhost/phpmyadmin

More documentation : file:///usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.3.11.1/share/phpmyadmin/doc/

Configuration has been copied to /usr/local/etc/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php
Don't forget to:
  - change your secret blowfish
  - uncomment the configuration lines (pma, pmapass ...)

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.3.11.1: 1,898 files, 55.2M, built in 2 seconds
```

I updated `httpd.conf` with that block of details. I also updated my blowfish and uncommented the configuration lines as it states.

When I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` i get a 404 error.

Any ideas where I would find the interface so I can more easily build/update my database(s).

Comment: Where did you get the phpmyadmin formula? Homebrew doesn't have it in the default repository. In any case, you should probably not install phpmyadmin using a package manager.

Comment: everything I did was from the repository. I'm also open to alternate suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this problem, too.

In order to use phpMyAdmin in your apache, you have to make symbolic link in `/usr/local/var/www/htdocs` with this command. (If you didn't changed your `DocumentRoot`)

```
cd /usr/local/var/www/htdocs
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.3.11.1/share/phpmyadmin ./phpmyadmin
```